# java gui builder custom jlabel

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans, builder

How do I add a custom `JLabel` in Netbeans' gui builder?

Comment: Do you mean to create a bean component that will be on the NetBeans' palette that you can drag and drop into your application?

Comment: actually I am creating more then one Jalabel at run time in normal java class within a panel but I want to add this pannel in gui builder with dynamic Jlabels.you can  say beans I tried by foolowin way but not succeeded                                                                         public class jpl extends JPanel {
JLabel lbl;                                                                public jpl(){
  for(int i=o;i<5;i++){
        lbl=new JLabel();
       lbl.setText("sdsd");
   add(lb);
    } }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just looking to see how to create JLabel's dynamically, you're close, although the snippet of code you posted in a comment has several errors in it.  Here's a similar example to your code:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Jpl extends JPanel {
    public static final String[] LABEL_TEXT = {"Monday", "Tuesday", 
        "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"};

    public Jpl() {
        for (int i = 0; i < LABEL_TEXT.length; i++) {
            JLabel lbl = new JLabel();
            lbl.setText(LABEL_TEXT[i]);
            add(lbl);
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Jpl");
        frame.getContentPane().add(new Jpl());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

If on the other hand, you're trying to create your own class that extends from JLabel that you can put in the NetBeans GUI-builder palette, then things will be a bit more difficult.

edit: but not impossible.  Custom components can be added via NetBeans Palette Manager.  For more on this, please check this link:  [Creating GUIs with NetBeans](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/tools/nb_guibuilder/) Check the section on Custom Components

Comment: yes I want to to put  dynamic created Jlabel in Netbeans gui builder  i am unable to that.

Comment: Please see edit to my post above on creating custom components and adding to NetBeans matisse's component palette.